# Client Server Messaging

Tags: php, web-applications, mariadb

I'm currently creating a web app. The app goes like this, the client creates something like reports in the web app, and we are using html5 and php and mariadb w/ phpmyadmin for our front end and database. And then, the report will send to the server. And the admin of the server will give response to the report. Now I am wondering on how the admin will response. Should I create a new webpage for the admin so he can receive the report? Should I use websocket? or is there something else? Any idea? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is your admin expected to respond to this report in real time? Or does it get added to a queue to be answered as time permits

Comment: yes sir the admin is expected to give a response, as soon as possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a web page report submission is inherently asynchronous (ie you don't know when it will occur), it follows that the admin response to submitted reports should also be asynchronous (since admins have to go to the toilet every now and then, much to the chagrin of management).

Your report system should post the report to a queue of 'to-be-processed' inbound reports. The admin could have either a web page portal (or a custom native applicatoin) for viewing pending reports. From there the admin can select one, view it, send client an update, close it. in other words, whatever host of actions the admin is expected to perform.

In this manner you can have a super admin interface that monitors one or more admins responding to reports and offers a higher level view of all the pending reports (time on queue) and the number of closed reports per admin per hour/day .. you could even make a graph..everyone likes graphs.

hope that helps.

Comment: yes i am planning to create an interface for the admin. But my groupmate is arguing me about this. She is telling me that I should stop minding this part of our app because when we upload our app to the web host it will just do the sending message function. Should I listen to her? She is insisting the web host thing. I am not very familiar with web host so it complicates my mind...

Comment: If the report which is sent to the sever gets stored in you database, the work flow I described would be acceptable. I can't comment on what your colleague is saying since I don't understand exactly what your claiming she is saying.